# Youtube videos stopped being displayed in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, youtube, video-streaming

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit with `The HTML5 player is currently used when possible` being enabled. Suddenly, youtube videos stopped showing but I still can hear videos' sounds. 
I don't have such problem in Firefox.

I looked at similar answers but none solved my problem. So appreciate your hints.